# Generic spider which can scrape any website using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape important data from websites. I want to write a generic spider definition which can scrape data from any website specified by the user. I have tried to write some code, but it is not sufficient to achieve my goal. This code is capable of scraping data, from some HTML tags only, which are sometimes unclear. This is the spider definition:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []

    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)

    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)


class StackItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.fields:
            self.fields[key] = scrapy.Field()
        self._values[key] = value

class betaSpider1(CrawlSpider):
    name = "betaSpider1"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(betaSpider1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        html_strip = MLStripper()
        item = StackItem()

        html_strip.feed(hxs.select("//a/@href").extract()[0])
        item['links'] = html_strip.get_data()

        html_strip.feed(hxs.select("//p").extract()[0])
        item['paragraph'] = html_strip.get_data()

        html_strip.feed(hxs.select("//div").extract()[0])
        item['div'] = html_strip.get_data()

        html_strip.feed(hxs.select("//span").extract()[0])
        item['span'] = html_strip.get_data()

        return item
```

Help me to convert this simple definition to a robust generic spider, which can scrape any website. Thanks

Comment: In my knowledge its not possible because each website has different source code different xpath. They may be using ajax calls which might need selenium.

Comment: @John Dene For example, there are some websites having almost similar structure. Can i achieve a part of above mentioned goal?

Comment: yes if what you state is correct you can deploy your spider on all those websites which have exactly similar xpath contents.

Comment: If you can mention the website names ,I will be able to tell you if the structure is same or not

Comment: @JohnDene  I am asking for almost similar, not exactly similar. Can we do that ??

Comment: Lets suppose following are some of the websites:

http://www.sarkarinaukriblog.com
http://www.sarkarinaukrisarch.in
http://www.freejobalert.com/government-jobs
https://www.sarkariexaam.com
http://www.sarkari-naukri.in

Comment: I think no you cant have generic spider for all these websites

Comment: What isn't working?  Your spider will do what you've instructed it to do, that is grab 'a', 'p', 'div', and 'span' tags and do stuff with them.  This will work on every site with those tags.  It's a generic spider that isn't site specific.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Results that are coming from this spider are absurd. I am not getting what i am intended to receive. I want to scrap important info like, job title , description etc from above mentioned websites. But it doesn't.